# how do i crawl the data of different links in a webpage after extracting them as well as add conditions?

Tags: python, database, csv, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook

I have a project that requires me to crawl all Egyptian movies from the period 2010 till now using a certain website and form a csv file with the tables required for a database(movie, cast, user rating, family rating, etc.) using beautifulsoup. the problem is that the data needed is inside every movie link I extracted but what I need to know is how to crawl the data inside each link. the conditions I need to add that I want only the movies and certain data such as the above (movie, cast, user rating, family rating, etc.).

```
parser = 'html.parser' 
resp = urllib.request.urlopen("https://elcinema.com/en/index/work/country/eg")
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, parser, from_encoding=resp.info().get_param('charset'))

for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print(link['href'])
```

note: I know you care about professionalism and I tried to follow the instructions. Also, I still learn and materials on such subject are few.

Comment: how about `urlopen( link['href'] )` in place of `print(link['href'])` ?

Comment: you should put code in function(s) and then you could use `function( link['href'] )` in place of `print(link['href'])`

Answer (score 0):

You should keep code in functions - ie. `parse_movie(url)`, `parse_main_page()` and then you could run `parse_movie(url)` inside `parse_main_page()` with `link['href']`

---

I could look like this - it needs code which get movie details and save in file so but I didn't test it.

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

parser = 'html.parser' 

# --- functions ---

def parse_movie(url):

    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, parser, from_encoding=resp.info().get_param('charset'))

    movie = []
    
    # ... code to get movie details ...
    # ... (movie, cast, user rating, family rating, etc.) ...

    return movie
    
    
def parse_main_page():

    resp = urllib.request.urlopen("https://elcinema.com/en/index/work/country/eg")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, parser, from_encoding=resp.info().get_param('charset'))

    all_movies = []
    
    for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
        movie = parse_movie( "https://elcinema.com" + link['href'] )
        all_movies.append(movie)
        
    return all_movies

# --- main ---

all_movies = parse_main_page()

print(all_movies)

# ... code to write `all_movies` in file ...
```

And now you should read doc for [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) because it has many functions and options.